# Is there a way to manually set the redirect URI for HWIOauthBundle?

Tags: symfony, oauth, hwioauthbundle

As I am currently working in a local development environment, I would like to change the redirect URI that the HWIOAuthBundle sends to any provider (e.g., Facebook). My aim is to use a service such as lvh.me or noip.com for the redirection back to my machine.

Is there a paarmeter that can be set to make that change?

Example:

Full request URL that my application is currently generating:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=123456&scope=email&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F**localhost**%2Fmyproject%2Fweb%2Fapp_dev.php%2Foauth%2Fcheck-facebook
```

I would like to change the `redirect_uri` parameter to something like

```
...&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flvh.me%2Fmyproject%2Fweb%2Fapp_dev.php%2Foauth%2Fcheck-facebook
```

or

```
...&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmyalias.noip.me%2Fmyproject%2Fweb%2Fapp_dev.php%2Foauth%2Fcheck-facebook
```

Answer (score 1):

In Security.yml, add the default_failure_path

```
oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook: '/login/check-facebook'
            login_path: /login
            failure_path: /login
            default_target_path: /home
```

You can configure the default_target_path, to whatever you want

```
default_target_path: %home%
```

Comment: The default_target_path only seems to take effect once the callback to my application has been made. Is that correct? I want to change the full URI in the 'redirect_uri' parameter of my request. I added an example in my original post.